# Formatting output in bash or awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following output

```
 Agnes               en_US    # Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?
 Albert              en_US    #  I have a frog in my throat. No, I mean a real frog!
 Bad News            en_US    # The light you see at the end of the tunnel is the headlamp of a fast approaching train.
 ...
```

What I want to do is to store the first field in a variable `x` and the third field in another variable `y`; The first field for the first line is `Agnes` and the third field is `Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?` The reason for doing so is to be able to have a `for` loop that execute a program with `$x` and `$y` as arguments.

I want to accomplish this task using Bash commands and AWK. Would you guys write a script that stores the first and third fields into variables, please?

Comment: did you want to store the first field on the first line only to x? What about the remaining lines?

Comment: _"What I want to do is to store the first field in a variable x  and the third field in another variable y"_ Are those `x` and `y` Bash or Awk variables?

Comment: What is the reason that you want to store them? What are you trying to do with them once they are stored?

Comment: It is not quite clear to me, but the title does not match well with the actual question. You will probably have to reformulate one or the other. Maybe both? As a last advice, please focus more on _what_ you are trying to do.

Comment: Are your fields separated by tabs or fixed-width or something else? Storing values in a variable is HOW you think you can do something, it doesn't tell us WHAT you want to do. Please update your question to show expected output given your sample input.

Comment: @TomFenech I would like to store them for each iteration and then run another command on them

Comment: @EdMorton The fields are separated with an fixed number of spaces

Comment: You should edit the question to add these additional details. Remember that the clearer your question, the more likely it is that someone can provide you a good answer.

Comment: @TomFenech Check the solution that `konsolebox` provided. It did the job for me.

Comment: It's good that you got your problem solved but your question is still unclear. Remember that answers to your question may be useful to others as well, so by making your question as clear as possible, you're adding something valuable to the site. Please consider editing your question to make it clearer what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

while read -r line; do
    x=${line%%  *}
    y=${line##*([^#])+(#)*([[:blank:]])}
    # Do something with $x and $y.
    echo "$x|$y"
done
```

Usage:

```
bash script.sh file
```

With Awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NF {
    x = $0
    sub(/  .*$/, "", x)
    sub(/^[ \t]*/, "", x)
    y = $0
    sub(/^[^#]+[#]+[ \t]*/, "", y)
    # Do something with x and y.
    printf "%s|%s\n", x, y
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Output:

```
Agnes|Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?
Albert|I have a frog in my throat. No, I mean a real frog!
Bad News|The light you see at the end of the tunnel is the headlamp of a fast approaching train.
```

Comment: * `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`

Comment: @konsolebox nice bsah solution. It did the job for me thanks a lot. Would you explain the following line ``${y##*([^#])+(#)*([[:blank:]])}``, please?

Comment: When `read x y` reads a line like `Agnes               en_US    # Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?`, `x` becomes `Agnes` and `y` becomes `en_US    # Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?`. What `${y##*([^#])+(#)*([[:blank:]])}` does is remove `en_US    # `. `##` is an operation to replace longest match starting at the beginning of the string; `*([^#])` means zero or more occurrences of anything that's not `#`; `+(#)` means one or more occurrences of `#`; `*([[:blank:]])` means zero of more occurrences of a blank character like space or tab.

Comment: Hover over the "add a comment" link and you will see: _"Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements."_ Again, why not just edit it in? It would make your answer much easier to read.

Comment: @TomFenech The answer stands enough on its own. I believe my explanation would suit well enough for the OP to understand even if it's just a comment. And it's also not necessary for others to get notified with it.

Comment: The answer is useless to anyone other than the original

Comment: @TomFenech Yes most of the time I only answer for the original.

Comment: The first output field should be "Bad News" instead of just "Bad".

Comment: I don't think you can assume there's always at least 2 spaces at the end of the first field and we're not even REALLY sure that the last field starts with a `#`, all we know for sure (because the OP told us in a comment) is that the fields are fixed-width.

Comment: @EdMorton Well I kind of seen that. I only used 2 spaces believing it would be enough however the OP can use 4 spaces if wanted. Now about `#` not being there or being somewhere, well the OP can just tell us about it. I've seen that possibility but I just chose not to complicate my code.

Comment: I actually meant there might just be 1 or even no spaces. Since it's fixed width fields the 2nd field might start immediately at the end of the first field (`Agnes FoobarWhateveren_US # stuff`) and so on. It is hard to tell though given just 3 input lines - you're probably right and there's more structure and rules to it than just "fixed width".

Answer (score 2):

If all you know for sure is that the fields are fixed-width:

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '{x=substr($0,1,20); y=substr($0,31); sub(/ +$/,"",x); sub(/^ +/,"",y); print x, y}' file
Agnes|Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?
Albert|I have a frog in my throat. No, I mean a real frog!
Bad News|The light you see at the end of the tunnel is the headlamp of a fast approaching train.
```

or if the last field really always starts with a # and there's no other `#` on the line:

```
$ awk -F'# *' -v OFS='|' '{sub(/ *[^ ]+ *$/,"",$1); print $1, $2}' file
Agnes|Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?
Albert|I have a frog in my throat. No, I mean a real frog!
Bad News|The light you see at the end of the tunnel is the headlamp of a fast approaching train.
```

If `|` doesnt work for you, pick your own separator and read it into whatever bash variables or array you like by setting IFS and using read -r, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' '{x=substr($0,1,20); y=substr($0,31); sub(/ +$/,"",x); sub(/^ +/,"",y); print x, y}' file |
while IFS='|' read -r x y; do printf "x=%s\ny=%s\n\n" "$x" "$y"; done
x=Agnes
y=Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?

x=Albert
y=I have a frog in my throat. No, I mean a real frog!

x=Bad News
y=The light you see at the end of the tunnel is the headlamp of a fast approaching train.
```

It's highly likely that this is not the best approach though, you'd probably be better off writing the rest of your script in awk.

In general consider GNU awk and FIELDWIDTHS for problems like this:

```
$ awk -v OFS='|' 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="20 10 999"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/^ +| +$/,"",$i); print $1, $3}' file
Agnes|Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?
Albert|I have a frog in my throat. No, I mean a real frog!
Bad News|The light you see at the end of the tunnel is the headlamp of a fast approaching train.
```

but IMHO it's not useful to make it gawk-specific for this particular 2-field problem.

Comment: +1 a nice summary of options, despite the lack of clarity in the question. I haven't seen `FIELDWIDTHS` before, it looks useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` with a `while` loop:

```
while IFS=@ read -ra arr; do
   printf "<%s>\n" "${arr[@]}"
done < <(awk -F ' {3,}' -v OFS=@ '{print $1, $3}' file.txt)
```

---

**Output:**

```
<Agnes>
<# Isn't it nice to have a computer that will talk to you?>
<Albert>
<#  I have a frog in my throat. No, I mean a real frog!>
<Bad News>
<# The light you see at the end of the tunnel is the headlamp of a fast approaching train.>
```

Answer (score 0):

An other solution:

```
awk -F '#' '{ 
              x = substr($1,1,20); # Assume fixed width format
              y = $2;
              sub(/^[ \t]*/,"",x); sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",x); # trim white spaces
              sub(/^[ \t]*/,"",y); sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",y); # trim white spaces

              # At this point x hold user name, y its comment
              print x ":" y;
              }' datafile
```

In that case, `x` and `y` will hold the correct values for each line in its turn.

If you really want to process only the first line, change to that:

```
awk -F '#' 'NR == 1 { 
              x = substr($1,1,20); # Assume fixed width format
              y = $2;
              sub(/^[ \t]*/,"",x); sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",x); # trim white spaces
              sub(/^[ \t]*/,"",y); sub(/[ \t]*$/,"",y); # trim white spaces

              # At this point x hold user name, y its comment
              print x ":" y;
              }' datafile
```